# Does the set of all 3x3 Elementary Matrices form a subspace of M3x3?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question :  Are 3x3 Elementary form matrices closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: How about writing down your two favourite elementary matrices and adding them?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "elementary matrix" ?

Comment: @Artem sorry i forgot to write my thoughts on this question section, please correct me if i'm wrong,  since elementary matrices are identity matrice which differ by one single elementary row operation, i think any result of addition and scalar multiplication to elementary matrice will not produce another elementary matrice, in conclusion the set will not form a subspace of M3x3 because it didn't meet the addition and scalar multiplication axiom, is that correct?

Comment: @Jean an elementary matrix is a matrix which differs from the identity matrix by one single elementary row operation. The elementary matrices generate the general linear group of invertible matrices

Comment: They do not constitute a subspace because it is not stable by multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: @Jean and by addition too correct?

Comment: It is neither stable by addition: $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$+$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ is not an elementary matrix because there is more than one 1 per line and per column.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither stable by addition: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
 is not an elementary matrix because there is more than one 1 per line and per column.

answered by @Jean Marie

Answer (score 0):

Note that the zero matrix is not an elementary matrix, which immediately implies that the collection of elementary matrices of a fixed size is not a subspace of the collection of all matrices of that size.